# python: dictionaries overwriting when using pythonic way

Tags: python

If I create a dictionary in a pythonic way, it gets overwritten

```
ans = ['car','bus']
exp = ['a','b']
for ex in exp:
     b ={x: {ex: {'1:N': [],'2:N': []}} for x in ans}
```

How do I avoid overwriting of an 'a' key?

Comment: What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: You're setting a list to a dictionary, not a dictionary to a dictionary.

Comment: Please be more clear what you want your final result to be exactly

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are beginner in Python so I would suggest break your program into smaller pieces to debug it. 
In your case dictionaries is getting overwritten because `=` operator always do reassignment that is create new copy and does not modify the existing variable even for mutable data types

If you break your code like this

```
ans = ['car','bus']
exp = ['a','b']


b = {x:{'1:N': [],'2:N': []} for x in exp} 
print(b)
```

It would give
`{'b': {'2:N': [], '1:N': []}, 'a': {'2:N': [], '1:N': []}}`

If you modify dictionary comprehension like this
`b = {a:{x:{'1:N': [],'2:N': []} for x in exp} for a in ans}`

then you would get the output
`{'bus': {'b': {'2:N': [], '1:N': []}, 'a': {'2:N': [], '1:N': []}}, 'car': {'b': {'2:N': [], '1:N': []}, 'a': {'2:N': [], '1:N': []}}}`

I believe this is what you want, let me know if it helps.